# Mistake in proving: $(xy)^2=xy$ for all $x,y\in G$ then G is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I was trying to prove that G is abelian but I actually ended up proving that $G=\{e\}$. This is much stronger than the question asked so I assumed that there must be a mistake in my argument. Can you help me find it?

$(xy)^2=xy\quad\forall x,y\in G$, in particular, if we fix $y=e$, we have $x^2=x\, \quad\forall x\in G$ so by the cancellation law (either by the left or by the right) we have $x=e\quad\forall x\in G$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect you have the question wrong. Perhaps the condition was $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2$ for all $x,y \in G$?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, I checked the book again and the question is exactly the one I posted. I guess the question in the book is kind of "absurd" then.

Comment: Right, you've proven correctly that if $(xy)^2=xy$ for all $x,y\in G$ then $G=\{e\}$, which is abelian. It's an odd question, but maybe trying to make you think through definitions.

Comment: That is exactly what I posted. I was asking if there's a mistake in the proof (I used exactly the same argument as you) or if this is just an awkward question (or a typo)  form the book.

Comment: @GerardGracia Yeah, I jumped the gun just reading the title, then immediately deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$(xy)^2=xy\quad\forall x,y\in G$ means that $xy=e$, so in particular $\quad\forall x \in G$ $x^{2} =e$  so $x=x^{-1}\quad\forall x\in G$.

let be $x,y \in G$ we have :

$xy=(xy)^{-1}$ so $xy=y^{-1}x^{-1}$ which means $xy=yx$.

finally G is abelian.

Comment: As the OP noted, it is not necessary to prove that $G$ is abelian, one can prove directly that $G$ must be trivial!

Comment: actually i ve just looked to the title so i did my proof